# Proxy a WS (web socket) connection?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a connection to a web socket but it is limited to the intranet. 
Looks like this:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://xx.xxx.6.98:8200/demo/");
```

It it possible to proxy it from the server side so it can become accessible from the outside world?

Something like:

```
socket = new WebSocket("ws://mysite.com/getWebSocket/demo/");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Nginx you can forward the traffic towards your destination server. Here is an example of how to proxy forward a Socket.IO Websocket.

```
location /socket.io/ {
    proxy_pass                      http://xx.xxx.6.98:8200;
    proxy_http_version              1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade        $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection     "upgrade";
}
```

Useful link: https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Answer (score 0):

Sure, what I do with SignalR is running it on a server, and expose it to the internet with ProxyPass on Apache.

So what you need is a Reverse Proxy, you can also let it work with Nginx but this is with Apache:

```
ProxyPass /ws ws://xx.xxx.6.98:8200/demo/
```

You have this on a domain or server IP, and when you go to ipaddressordomain.com/ws you actually go to ws://xx.xxx.6.98:8200/demo/

Comment: Mine was very basic, Olle's answer is more detailed :)